# Inserting new rows to the table used for cursor, inside the cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looping through the rows of a temporary table using cursor and inside the cursor I am inserting new rows to the same table used for cursor.

What behaviour I have noticed is that the cursor doesn't include new rows that gets added within the cursor.
For my requirement this is what I wanted but I am not sure the behavior I am noticing is correct because my query is complex and I don't know if it can fail later if my observation of the behaviour is wrong.

So doesn't cursor consider rows of the table that was added later inside the cursor?

Comment: can you please add your code?

Comment: No, it won't. When you declare a `CURSOR`, you use the dataset at the time that was produced; if that dataset changes afterwards the `CURSOR` won't see this, as its already got the data it needs (otherwise, you would have some very long locks on your table!). Do you really need to use a `CURSOR` though? A dataset approach would be far better, if possible.

Comment: @MoinulIslam - I don't think the query is needed. I have explained the scenario

Comment: I agree, the query would really help. I imagine this is actually an xy question and the query will greatly help with that.

Comment: @Larnu  - Actually yes, my requirement is to get the hierarichal structure of the data using common table expression, plus the child can have multiple instances. So to generate this I have to first get the hierarchy using CTE and then have to loop to see what all structures withing the hierarchy I have to repeat based on maximum number of instances

Comment: There are far better options than using a `CURSOR` for a hierarchy in SQL Server. For example: [Hierarchies on Steroids](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Hierarchy/94040/)

Comment: @Larnu - I am not using Cursor for hierarchy, I am using CTE for it. After CTE I am using cursor to repeat child structure to its maximum possible instances

Comment: I still doubt a `CURSOR` is needed, but without the query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All static cursors takes a snapshot of the data into tempdb, any change in the underlying data will not impact the change.

If you want the impact to appear, you can use dynamic cursor in SQL Server.

You can read more on dynamic cursor [here](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/dynamic-cursor-in-sql-server/) and [here](https://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/feature/Part-1-How-cursors-work)